# Copying projects/solutions from VS2015 to VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have a number of projects and solutions developed under Visual Studio 2015 and sitting underneath my `Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects` folder.

I want to copy the projects over to my VS2017 instance for transition testing, so that they sit under `Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects`.

I have a *vague* recollection that this hasn't worked out so well before due to paths being stored in the various Visual Studio files. In addition, when doing a demo run with a scratch project, the time stamp of the project file in VS2015 was updated, even though it appears no files *within* there were changed.

Is it safe just to copy over the directories and open the solution files with the newer Visual Studio.

Note that I *don't* want to affect the original files in any way, they need to stay in VS2015 land.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, it appears this is safe.

Tests involved copying the directories as they were over to the VS2017 area, then renaming the top level of the VS2015 area so that any references, should they exist, would more than likely show up as an error.

With the old area renamed, the copied solutions could be opened in VS2017 without issue, and upgraded to that toolset.

The updating of the directory timestamp was almost certainly a different issue, probably because I had opened one of the files *in* that directory with `vim`, which created and deleted a temporary file.